# Detect if string has substring from array of possibilities

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to check whether a string contains any substring in an array?

Say I have `bad_words = ['broccoli', 'cabbage', 'kale']`, and `my_string = "My shopping list features pizza, gummy bears, kale, and vodka."` I want to check whether `my_string` has any of the `bad_words` items within it without using a loop/iterator. Is this possible?

It seems like people use `Array#index` to solve this problem, but I'm not sure how because, in my tests, it only returns `true` if the entire argument matches an entire item from the array: `bad_words.index "kale"` returns an index but `bad_words.index "no kale"` returns `nil`. So it's no good for substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_string =~ /\b#{Regexp.union(bad_words)}\b/
#=> 46
```

will do.

Comment: Clever and effective, I wouldn't have thought of this. Thanks!